# Can you identify the manufacturer or specific design of these chess pieces?

Tags: chessboards, identify-this

I was wondering if anyone could identify the manufacturer of these chess pieces, or possibly the name of its design (beyond just "Staunton". It's correct I think, but want to know more)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is beautiful set, and a nice photo. I imagine it is a family heirloom that has gained a nice patina from much use. It looks very much like one of the original sets from the 1800s by Jacques of London and I would go to their website. https://houseofstaunton.com

In the early sets, rather delightfully, the rooks had a small K or Q symbol engraved inside the turret, so that, in the manner of the time, you could write the score as "Kings Rook at the adverse Queens Bishops square, giving Checkmate"

Comment: That would be incredible! It lacks a few of the details of many Jaques of London sets as far as I can tell, but the patina is there and it is lovely. I picked it up yesterday on Ebay Kleinanzeigan (German ebay) for 40€! It has now fallen into the hands of some chess-keen philosophy students living in Berlin. This shall be an absolute treasure. I'll update if I find out anything more.

Comment: Did such sets also distinguish the KN from the QN? and, if so, where on the piece?

Comment: Lucky you!!!!!!

Comment: @RosieF: If the knights are faced inward at the start of the game, and not rotated, their orientation would indicate their origin.  On the other hand, I find myself wondering how notation which distinguishes between the knights or rooks would handle scenarios involving underpromotion to such pieces, or for that matter to a bishop which occupies the same color squares as another live bishop.

Comment: @supercat The object of old-fashioned notation was to to use the least amount of information that would avoid ambiguity and place least strain on the reader. So KR-K5 if it was still obvious which Rook had started where, or R(7)-K5 if there was risk of confusion. Similarly for all the other cases you mention. This is context-dependent and a bit subjective; hence the change. But echoes of descriptive notation, like "a Rook on the seventh" are immensely valuable.

Answer (score 3):

It's design is called Staunton, named after chessmaster Howard Staunton (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staunton_chess_set).

This chess set is the FIDE official recommended one for tournaments.

Comment: It's not quite standard Staunton.  The Staunton king has a cross, while this has a more complex symbol.